# User LogIn with social provider’s [facebook] token for QuickBlox

Tags: ios, swift, chat, quickblox

I have two Button on MainView controller.

1-Login to facebook

```
func loginWithFacebook( withCompletionHandler: (Void)->(Void) ) {

    let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {

        }
        else {
            withCompletionHandler()

        }
    }
}
```

and  second button is
2- Login Using Quickblox

func loginForQuickBloxUsingSocialProvider(  ){

```
    QBRequest.logInWithSocialProvider("facebook", accessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString, accessTokenSecret: nil,
        successBlock: {(response:QBResponse!, user:QBUUser?)-> Void in

            print(response)

            print("current User:\(user)")

        }, errorBlock: {(response:QBResponse!)-> Void in
           SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
           // print("error:\(response)")


    })
}
```

But there is no affect and end with errorBlock: {(response:QBResponse!)-> Void in

I want app user to login with facebook for Quickblox

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your facebook access token is correct one, try some facebook requests with it. If facebook access token is fine, then check if token string from FBSDKAccessToken is correctly unwrapped.

Otherwise please provide complete error that you are getting.